# Is it possible to buy upgraded versions of games you already own on Steam?

Tags: steam

I already own Deus Ex: Human Revolution - the regular edition, and it is linked to my Steam account. I would like to buy the 'Augmented Edition' which is now at a 75% discount (I like the soundtrack, and want the making of videos).

Right now it doesn't seem possible to buy the other version. Is there some workaround?

Comment: You can *buy* the other version, if that's what you're asking.  I think some games let you upgrade, but I've never seen any.

Comment: It's not direct answer, rather some additional insight. When usually I buy game, years later there appears bundle with vanilla game and 10 its DLCs. So I buy bundle, activate all DLCs im missing so far and send rest to some my friends.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the game.

If you have the regular edition of Civilization V, for instance, you are able to upgrade to the Game of the Year edition, which features all but two of the released DLC, plus the soundtrack.

If such an upgrade *is* available, the "buy" option will change to "upgrade" (as long as you're already logged in to your steam account).

Comment: So basically, if I already own a game, there is no way for me to get the soundtrack through Steam unless the game is upgradeable?

Comment: @erikric Again, depends on the game. I was able to buy the Bastion soundtrack as a standalone, for instance.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this was available.